# spresenseがzerynth stdioでデバイスの登録ができませんでした

Tags: python, spresense

SpresenseをPythonで動かすためにZerynth Studioというアプリを使用手順に従い、デバイスの登録をしようとしました。登録は、registerボタンをクリックすることでZerynthが自動でやってくれます。

しかし、登録中"Can't find a chipid"と表示され、登録ができません。
デバイスマネージャでデバイスのidを確認したところ、idは確かに存在し、またZerynthに接続しているデバイス情報を確認してもidを認識していました。登録するときにだけidが認識できないようです。そのあたりに詳しい方にもみていただきましたが、改善できず、初期不良が考えられるということでその時はまとまりました。

そのときの挙動を示したスクリーンショットを載せます。
もし対処法を知っている方がいらっしゃいましたら、方法をご教授していただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**デバイス登録操作時のアプリの挙動:**

[image: デバイス登録操作時のアプリの挙動]

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the Sony Spresense board with latest version of Zerynth studio, I couldn't replicate your error as I was able to register and virtualize the device.
For troubleshooting, Which version of Zerynth studio and OS are you using?

Please check that you have the appropriate software drivers for the board, more information about the drivers [are in this link.](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/set-up-the-arduino-ide#_prerequisites)
Please also try to use another cable as some issues arise when cables cannot provide sufficient power.
For more information about the board, please [check Zerynth documentation](https://docs.zerynth.com/latest/reference/boards/sony_spresense/docs/)

Feel free to ask if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

I just didn't install the driver on the Spresense.
After that, the device worked fine.

I'm sorry to have taken the trouble.